# How can I export a .FBX file from Unity3D at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity, fbx, export

I want to export an object as a `.fbx` at runtime in Unity3D.

I've made a C# script to export a mesh filter or skinned mesh renderer to a `.obj` file at runtime, but I want the animation and skin support that only `.fbx` supports.

After some research, using the Autodesk FBX SDK or some other external `.dll` seems like my best option. How do I call Autodesk's FBX SDK at runtime? Is there another external `.dll`s I could use for this?

Another option could possibly be to write the mesh information as a text file, then convert to `.fbx` to export.

Comment: Does it have to be FBX?  That's a proprietary, mostly undocumented format that most people can only access via the FBX SDK.  Compare to, say, Collada, which is open and well-documented and should work in whatever tool you're loading the generated FBX into.

Comment: More to the point, why are you exporting at runtime? There might be another solution for what you actually want to do other than the solution you think you need to do.

Comment: Does Collada support skinned mesh renderers and animations? If so something like that may work, I was just told FBX because of the information it can hold and because it works for any 3D platform. And I'm exporting at runtime because that's the entire purpose of this script, essentially the user can adjust the mesh and textures on their character, then press an "Export" button and download the textures and .fbx for the character. This is all done in the web player, I have it working with textures, animations, and .OBJ. But I'd like .FBX because it supports skinned mesh renderers and animations

Comment: However, if I could export to another supported 3D format that would be able to hold skin information and special animation information that would work even better than .FBX.

Comment: @TimothyWilliams Collada supports skinning and animations.

Comment: I have write some C sharp scripts write ascii type FBX file(cubes like).
But it is hard to gen complex files.
I have some common ideas with you, if you have any advance in your idea, pls share some information with me.

Answer (score 1):

Autodesk has a [FBX Converter](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=20481519), which can take .objs and output .fbx. Included is a command line tool, which you could call from your game at runtime. As long as you do not want to have that functionality distributed to every player, that should be enough.

Comment: Though the comments above are useful, this does directly answer the question.